# Jinja {% extends %}

Tags: html, django, jinja2

Okay, so I have this first HTML file (header.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>M4A</title>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/header.css' %}" />
<link rel="icon" href="../../static/image/logo.png">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f9f9f9">
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/"><img src="../../static/image/logoRect.png" width="25"> </a></li>
        <li><a href="/movies">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a class="left" href="">Search</a></li>
        <li><a class="left" href="/profile/">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a class="left" href="#about">Explore</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And then I have this other one (home.html):

```
{% extends "START/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p> TEST</p> <!-- for example -->

{% endblock %}
```

but when running the second one it doesn't extend really, it looks like its replacing the content of the other HTML file's body. the background color is still the one in my css file though so I'm sure it's reading it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are replacing the body when you use the same block tag in your home.html that in your header.html

```
{% block content %}
```

You should use a different name if you dont want to replace it.

In addition you can use:

```
{{ block.super() }}
```

If you want to extend the block content data, notice it's a different issue from extending a template.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to put the {% block content %} tag right before the {% endblock %}

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are expecting.

The [Jinja documentation about templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/) is pretty clear about what a block does:

> All the `block` tag does is tell the template engine that a child template may override those placeholders in the template.

In your example, the base template (header.html) has a default value for the content block, which is everything inside that block. By setting a value in home.html, you are *overriding* that default value with another block.

If you want to *add* content below your navigation menu, simply rework your template to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>M4A</title>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/header.css' %}" />
<link rel="icon" href="../../static/image/logo.png">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f9f9f9">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/"><img src="../../static/image/logoRect.png" width="25"> </a></li>
    <li><a href="/movies">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a class="left" href="">Search</a></li>
    <li><a class="left" href="/profile/">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a class="left" href="#about">Explore</a></li>
</ul>
{% block content %}<p>This will appear if you don't set a block in the inheriting template.</p>{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>M4A</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/header.css' %}" />
    <link rel="icon" href="../../static/image/logo.png">
    </head>

    {% block content %}
     <body class="body" style="background-color:#f9f9f9">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="../../static/image/logoRect.png" width="25"> </a></li>
            <li><a href="/movies">Movies</a></li>
            <li><a class="left" href="">Search</a></li>
            <li><a class="left" href="/profile/">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a class="left" href="#about">Explore</a></li>
        </ul>
     </body>
    {% endblock %}

    </html>
```

make body inside in block and change body backgound

```
{% extends "START/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f23d49">
    <p> TEST</p> <!-- for example -->
</body>
{% endblock %}
```